# why my query is not sargable

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have very strange problem.

I have query like this which I run in SQL server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT TOP (20) *
FROM MyTable
WHERE a = 0
    AND b = 0
    AND c = 0
```

that uses my index on MyTable

but this one doesn't:

```
SELECT TOP (20) *
FROM MyTable
WHERE a = 0
    OR b = 0
    OR c = 0
```

and i want to execute second query in my program. how do I alter the second query to use the index?

the index is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable] (
[a] ASC,
[b] ASC,
[c] ASC
)
WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
        ONLINE = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: It won't. It would have to search the entire index in order to find rows that just match the `LicenseDelete=0` condition (because the `IRDelete` and `ColorDelete` values could be anything)

Comment: For the same reason that you can easily use a phone book to find someone whose first name is "Martin" and last name "Smith" but finding people with first name "Martin" *or* last name "Smith" is much more work. The phone book is not ordered by first name so finding the Martins involves reading the whole thing.

Comment: did you mean that 'or' operator always ruins Indexes? is not any way to fix MyIndex to cover the where clause?

Comment: @user1121366 - Yes. An "or" can't use an index. Except for the case where you have separate indexes on the or-ed columns in which case you *might* get an index union plan which seeks the multiple indexes and combines the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use that one index for a query which has `or` between conditions. Just think about it: any one of the values can match so the index matching can't guarantee that there are no other records matching that criteria.

It is really like running separate searches and then matching them together.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Index, SQL-Server checks for lot of things

**1)** If the filter is SARG.

**2)** Index use likelihood ratio (No of unique records : total no of records)

**3)** No of records to fetch (if less records, index may be used or else table scan. Because sql-server finds it easy to scan the whole table than to locate and use index if amount of records is huge.)

**4)** In your Query, because you are using `OR`, No of records increases, in which condition, sql-server finds it easy to scan the whole table than to locate/use index. If it is `AND`, likelihood of Index use will increase.

Answer (score 0):

What the other answerers have said is true. However, you can use a trick:

```
SELECT TOP (20) *
(
select TOP(20) *
FROM MyTable
WHERE a = 0

union

SELECT TOP(20) *
FROM MyTable
WHERE b = 0

union

SELECT TOP(20) *
FROM MyTable
WHERE c = 0
)
```

Each of the individual subqueries can use a separate index. So, now all you need are 3 separate indexes (one each where the leading column is a, b, and c) and you're good to go.